# NFC Tag to count number of taps

Tags: count, touch, nfc

Hy!

I am working on my NFC project for my diploma thesis and I want to make 2 things:

1) When I tap NFC tag with my phone I want that browser on my phone connect me to my website.

2) I want to make that my NFC tag count numbers of taps so I can later read that number with my android app and send it to database on my server, so I can make statistics about how many times my NFC tag has been tapped.

I have accomplished my first task and my phone browser propertly display my website when I tap NFC tag but now I have problem with my second task. 
I have searched on internet for some tutorials and I havent found any good tutorial how to programm NFC tag to count numbers of taps and its not as simple as with website url, so I am asking myself, maybe its not even possible to make it. I think, if NFC tag can save whole URL of website it must be possible to save single integer number and do basic `Number_of_taps + = 1` thing.

If anyone knows good solution or link of some good tutorial pls post it. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There are new NFC tags coming to the market right now that can do exactly what you want. Examples of these are NXP's [NTAG213 and related](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) tag ICs. They have the functionality to increase a counter every time the tag is read and embed an ASCII value representing that counter into the URL in an NDEF message. See section 8.7.2 of the linked datasheet for the details.

Comment: I have already bought my NFC tags, I dont have time to order those new tags, but thx for trying to help...

Answer (score 2):

The **tag** will not do the counting for you.

Add a record to your **NDEF message** which holds the counter value. When the user taps the **tag**, your app gets the actual counter value. You can now increase the value by 1. Then you can write the value back on the **tag**. Be aware that this may have timing implications when a user removes the **tag** before the new value has been written.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer, but I still dont know how to add record to my NFC message (I think that u mean NDEF record), I shoould programm my own android app only for doing that or there is other way to do it ?

Comment: Adding / modifying a record in your NDEF message can be done via app that you develop yourself. If you want to avoid that, you may consider to have the counter on your website.

In that case you should use unique numbers (e.g. the UID) as a part of the NDEF message, so that your web application can differentiate the various tags.